# Derangement of Odd Objects

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, derangements

I was recently learning the concept of derangement of $n$ objects and I did not want to mug up the formula so instead, I solved by inclusion-exclusion principle.
The question was to find the number of ways in which $4$ envelopes none of them can be placed in the correct place. I know it can be solved by the derangement formula $$n! \left(1- \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} - \frac{1}{3!} + \frac{1}{4!}+ (-1)^n\frac{1}{n!} \right ).$$ 
and for $n=4$ we get, $$n(D) = 9$$ I solved this by the concept of inclusion-exclusion and long story short, I got this formula, $$n(D) =  n! - \sum ^ {n} _{k=1} \binom{n}{k}.$$ 
However I am not able to use this when $n$ is of the form $2n-1$ $\forall \; n \gt 2$.  This I realized is because we cannot derange $1$ object only out of  $3,5,7,9...2n-1$ objects.
So can anyone tell me how to go about how to derive a formula like this for $2n-1$ objects.

Comment: Your formula for $n(D)$ yields a negative number when $n = 2$.

Comment: Your formula states $n(D)=n!+1-2^n$. That's not correct. I don't see what your comments on odd numbers are all about.

Comment: I know, so I get that the formula isn't universal. I just want to find a formula that describes the $n(D) \forall \; 2n-1$

Comment: Why not simply use the well-known formula for derangements:  $!n=(n-1)(!(n-1)+!(n-2))$ where $!n=n!\sum _{i=0}^{n}{\frac {(-1)^{i}}{i!}}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I got the formula $n!-\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}k.$

This is incorrect. The correct formula is $n!-\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1}\binom{n}k (n-k)!$.

> we cannot derange $1$ object out of $3,5,\dots,2n-1$.

This has nothing to do with the problem at hand. Sure, it is impossible to choose a permutation so exactly one object is out of place. This is also true when the number of objects is even. But the problem is about deranging *all* of the objects, not just one of them, so this does not matter.

Comment: All right I think I understand. I will go over my working again. Thank you